# Greying out/disabling a textbox based on selected text in the dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, dropdown

I am trying to grey out textboxes based on the selected text in a dropdown list. I have an onChange function for the dropdown but it doesn't seem to be doing the trick

**My html**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SponsorName, employmentStatuses, "Select Employment Status", new { id = "employmentStatus", @class = "form-control", onchange = "GetSelectedTextValue(this)" })
```

The textbox that should be greyed out if the user selected that they are unemployed

```
 <div class="col-sm-3">
    Employer
    <div>
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Employer, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "employer", @class = "form- 
    control" } })@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Employer, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
  </div>
```

My script for the onChange Function

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            function GetSelectedTextValue(ddlEmploymentStatus) {
                var selectedText = ddlEmploymentStatus.options[ddlEmploymentStatus.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
                var selectedValue = ddlEmploymentStatus.value;
                if (selectedText != 'Employed' || selectedText !='Self employed')
                {

                    document.getElementById("employer").disable = 'true';
                    document.getElementById("JobTitle").disable = 'true';

                }
                alert(selectedText);
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: disabled is a bool  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_disabled.asp

Answer (score 1):

There's three main issues in your code.

- The correct property name is `disabled`, not `disable`.
- The `disabled` property accepts a boolean value, not a string.
- The logic in the `if` condition is flawed as the two conditions are mutually exclusive. This means that you need to invert the condition to check.

In addition you should not use inline event handlers as they are outdated and bad practice as they violate the Separation of Concerns principle. It's better practice to add your event handlers unobtrusively, like this:

```js
document.querySelector('#employmentStatus').addEventListener('change', function() {
  let selectedText = this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  let isDisabled = !(selectedText == 'Employed' || selectedText == 'Self employed');
  document.querySelector('#employer').disabled = isDisabled;
  document.querySelector('#JobTitle').disabled = isDisabled;
});
```

```html
<select id="employmentStatus" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Please select...</option>
  <option value="Student">Student</option>
  <option value="Unemployed">Unemployed</option>
  <option value="Employed">Employed</option>
  <option value="Self employed">Self employed</option>
</select>

<div class="col-sm-3">
  Employer
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="employer" class="form-control" disabled="disabled" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  Job title
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="JobTitle" class="form-control" disabled="disabled"  />
  </div>
</div>
```

One last minor thing to note is that the casing of your `id` attributes is inconsistent and should be corrected.